# Windows 10 Preview not enabling tablet mode

Tags: windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface-pro

I've just installed Windows 10 Technical Preview on my Surface Pro 3 and for some reason I can't seem to activate the tablet mode - as you can see in the screenshot taken from the Windows 10 Preview video it should automatically come up when the type cover is removed. But for some the message never comes up. Is there a manual way to enter tablet mode in the current Windows 10 Technical Preview?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem.  As for what is shown in the video that is easily explain because Microsoft has the capabilities to resolve the driver problem.  As I suspected....**This is a feature of `Continuum` which isn't in the current release of Windows 10**

Comment: So is there any way to enable the tablet mode manually in the current build?

Comment: What part of "its not in the current release" wasn't clear?  The video showed features of `Continuum` which have not been enabled nor exist in the current released build of `Windows 10` as of 11/14/2014

Comment: I understood in that way that the auto-detection feature is missing, not the whole feature. But I've got what you mean now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're describing is known as Continuum and as of the current build (9879) this has not been enabled by Microsoft.

There is however a registry hack to enable what has been included in the build. Now I'm sure we've all read (and ignored) registry warnings before, but:

**This relates to a feature that not meant to be enabled on a pre-release operating system. Do not attempt this if you're not in a position whereby you could wipe and reinstall your device, and do not use this on a production machine (then again, you probably shouldn't be using Windows 10 Preview on a production machine anyway, but I digress...)**

**Also note, I haven't tested this personally**

With that in mind, if you want to continue, you'll need to:

1. Open your registry editor and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher`
2. Create a new DWORD (32-bit) Value, name it `UseExperience` and give it the value of `1`
3. Sign out and back in or restart the computer

[Source](http://microsoft-news.com/registry-hack-will-allow-you-to-experience-a-glimpse-of-continium-feature-in-windows-10/)